# How to test the handlers in withHandlers, branch and withState of recompose with enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, recompose

I'm new to enzyme testing and I've made a component as :

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  compose,
  withState,
  withHandlers,
  branch,
  pure,
  renderComponent,
} from 'recompose';

import Fields from './components/Fields';
import Flow from './components/Flow';

export const MODE = {
  preview: 'preview',
  edit: 'edit',
};

const inEditMode = ({ mode }) => mode === MODE.edit;

const Component = branch(
  inEditMode,
  renderComponent(Fields),
  renderComponent(Flow),
)(Flow);

const Tab = pure(props => <Component {...props} />);

export default compose(
  withState('mode', 'changeMode', props => {
    const path = props.path;

    return props.path ? MODE.preview : MODE.edit;
  }),
  withHandlers({
    changeMode: ({ changeMode }) => () => changeMode(currentState => currentState === MODE.preview ? MODE.edit : MODE.preview),
    onApprovalChange: ({ onAction, entity }) => data => {
      onAction({ ...data, status: 'UPDATED' }, data.id);
    },
  }),
)(Tab);
```

In the above component, I want to test the following thing :

1. The rendering of the `Component`
2. `inEditMode` function of the component
3. Handlers present in `withState` and `withHandlers`
4. `branch` utility of recompose (I don't really think I need to check this because they might've already but suppose I want to test such function)

I could find some documentation on stackoverflow about testing but there was not one resource which could give overall idea.

Comment: You can take a look into this comment for a workaround: https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/issues/407#issuecomment-309075313

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing your component, you should test only your component, not the containers (the functions wrapping it) as they are **higher order components**.

If you want to test the functions from `recompose` look at their own tests: [https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/src/packages/recompose/**tests**/withState-test.js](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/src/packages/recompose/__tests__/withState-test.js)
and just write your own based on that.

As for your component, make sure you export the individual parts and test them. In your scenario will be the functional component `inEditMode`:

```
export const inEditMode = ({ mode }) => mode === MODE.edit;
```

That's all you need to test on this component.

Comment: Why not testing the containers? I think it is preferable to test the whole thing, that's the way it is going to be consumed anywhere else. The props passed by recompose are just implementation details.

Comment: @MiguelCarvajal The same way you'll not define a function every time you use it, you'll not test it when you use it. If I define a utils "parseAtoB" that is used in 10 components, doesn't make sense to check "if the input is A returns B" on every component. Of course I can protect my application by building a test for a third party library that I'm using, making sure the library keeps doing what I need it to do. But later I just need to test that I called the right function "component C calls parseAtoB" and expect the util to do what is meant to do.